# How to Insert Data into the Database Using API POST Request in (React Native Axios)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm currently new to React Native, **is there an easy way to determine what kind of error throws in my alert on my response?**

I have a module where I insert the data in the database using an axios post request, but the alert shows this error:

[image: Alert Show]

**My function for inserting data in the database (From React JS api):**

```
  const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('driver_id','1');
    formData.append('driver_route_lat',this.state.updatedLocation.latitude);
    formData.append('driver_route_long',this.state.updatedLocation.longitude);


    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/update_driver_route_logs',{
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: formData,
      }).then((resp) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(resp));
      }).catch(err => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(err));
    })
```

**ReactJS Controller:**

```
   class MobileController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function update_driver_route_logs(Request $request) {

        $driver_id = $request->get('driver_id');
        $driver_route_lat = $request->get('driver_route_lat');
        $driver_route_long = $request->get('driver_route_long');    
        $now = new DateTime();

        $update_driver_route = DB::insert('
        INSERT INTO driver_route_logs 
        SET 

            driver_id = ?,
            route_lat = ?,
            route_long = ?,
            route_created = ?

        VALUES (?,?,?,?)

        ',[$driver_id,$driver_route_lat,$driver_route_long,$now]);

        if($update_driver_route) {
            return response()->json('New Location Found');
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `127.0.0.1` refers to the current machine, in this case the Android device / emulator. You need to send the request to your computer though.

Comment: What do you mean for that bro @ChrisG?

Comment: do i need to change the ip address or the port?

Comment: try with localhost instead of IP, i think that's what @ChrisG meant

Comment: The IP address. Your computer probably has one like `192.168.1.25` or something like that. Open the command prompt and enter `ipconfig`

Comment: @hardworker `localhost` is an alias for `127.0.0.1` and also points to the same machine. How would `localhost` magically refer to the correct computer inside the LAN?

Comment: 192.xxx.1xx.xx i make this secret first, yes this is my ip, bro @ChrisG what should I do?

Comment: First, stop calling me "bro". Next, put the computer's IP in your JS code, where it says `127.0.0.1` now. You need `axios("http://192.168.1xx.xx:8000/api/...`

Comment: Or run `adb reverse tcp:8000 tcp:8000` in your android studio terminal

Comment: @ChrisG it seems, the data not insert into the database.

Comment: 1. use the most basic way to test this (create a GET endpoint in your API, open the URL from your Android's browser, check if you can see the response, *then* move to AJAX) 2. do debugging. `console.log()` *everything* 3. if you need help, *post **all** relevant code*, explain what you did, how it failed, etc etc. DO. THE. WORK.

Comment: @ChrisG is the debugger it shows Error: Network Error

Comment: 4. read my comments and follow them, if you want my help. Bye.